# md0 mount comes read-only after some writing

Tags: linux, read-only, md

So I got a RAID 6 array (monitored) and I mount it to my filesystem (/mnt/mounting_point for this example). After some writing, for example:

`sudo fio --name=seqwrite --filename=/test/seqwrite.0.0 --rw=write --bs=1M --numjobs=8 --time_based --runtime=60 --size=10G --ioengine=libaio --direct=1`

I only can read from my filesystem, the above command will fail after 25%, then it doesn't write anymore, up until that point it was running fine at 2000MB/s). This will not only happen when writing with fio, but also when I let it run my database server for a while. It will eventually stop writing and can only read (so queries WILL run, INSERTS will fail).

It will happely report raid is working fine:

```
           Version : 1.2
     Creation Time : Thu Aug 17 09:24:45 2023
        Raid Level : raid6
        Array Size : 7813772288 (7.28 TiB 8.00 TB)
     Used Dev Size : 3906886144 (3.64 TiB 4.00 TB)
      Raid Devices : 4
     Total Devices : 4
       Persistence : Superblock is persistent

     Intent Bitmap : Internal

       Update Time : Wed Oct  4 06:10:46 2023
             State : active 
    Active Devices : 4
   Working Devices : 4
    Failed Devices : 0
     Spare Devices : 0

            Layout : left-symmetric
        Chunk Size : 512K

Consistency Policy : bitmap

              Name : dh-n1:0
              UUID : 915e7624:bb97c5f3:b9441100:47906eac
            Events : 48569

    Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice State
       0     259        3        0      active sync   /dev/nvme3n1
       1     259        1        1      active sync   /dev/nvme2n1
       4     259        2        2      active sync   /dev/nvme1n1
       3     259        0        3      active sync   /dev/nvme0n1
```

`dmesg | grep md0` will only show:

```
[   15.248686] md/raid:md0: device nvme0n1 operational as raid disk 3
[   15.258967] md/raid:md0: device nvme2n1 operational as raid disk 1
[   15.271897] md/raid:md0: device nvme1n1 operational as raid disk 2
[   15.285967] md/raid:md0: device nvme3n1 operational as raid disk 0
[   15.353946] md/raid:md0: raid level 6 active with 4 out of 4 devices, algorithm 2
[   15.377809] md0: detected capacity change from 0 to 15627544576
[   34.665129] EXT4-fs (md0): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Quota mode: none.
```

`fsck.ext4 -y /dev/md0` will not fail and say everything is ok

When it failes, `ps aux` will show half of the processes, and I have to cancel it using CTRL + C

Also `top` will halt loading processes, which I cannot cancel or close

`rm /mnt/mounting_point/file.img` will run forever

`nano /mnt/mounting_point/file.txt` will just show content

dmesg won't show any other errors

/proc/cmdline:

```
boot.img root=/dev/ram0 console=tty1 systemd.unified_cgroup_hierarchy=1 cgroup_no_v1=all iommu.passthrough=1
```

`top` will say this (and will hang):

```
Mem: 32029768K used, 231099124K free, 1188620K shrd, 492976K buff, 16871968K cached
CPU:   0% usr   0% sys   0% nic  91% idle   7% io   0% irq   0% sirq
[And shows some non relevant processes]
```

Linux version 6.1.55

**Edit**:

`/proc/mdstat` during the failure

```
Personalities : [raid6] [raid5] [raid4] 
md0 : active raid6 nvme1n1[4] nvme0n1[3] nvme2n1[1] nvme3n1[0]
      7813772288 blocks super 1.2 level 6, 512k chunk, algorithm 2 [4/4] [UUUU]
      bitmap: 5/30 pages [20KB], 65536KB chunk
```

`mount` shows:

```
rootfs on / type rootfs (rw)
devtmpfs on /dev type devtmpfs (rw,relatime,size=131532284k,nr_inodes=32883071,mode=755)
proc on /proc type proc (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
sysfs on /sys type sysfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
securityfs on /sys/kernel/security type securityfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
tmpfs on /dev/shm type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev)
devpts on /dev/pts type devpts (rw,nosuid,noexec,relatime,gid=5,mode=620,ptmxmode=000)
tmpfs on /run type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,size=52625756k,nr_inodes=819200,mode=755)
cgroup2 on /sys/fs/cgroup type cgroup2 (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
pstore on /sys/fs/pstore type pstore (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
bpf on /sys/fs/bpf type bpf (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,mode=700)
hugetlbfs on /dev/hugepages type hugetlbfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,pagesize=2M)
mqueue on /dev/mqueue type mqueue (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
debugfs on /sys/kernel/debug type debugfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
tmpfs on /tmp type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,size=131564384k,nr_inodes=1048576)
configfs on /sys/kernel/config type configfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
/dev/md0 on /mnt/k3s type ext4 (rw,relatime,stripe=256)
[...] removed the kubernetes mounts
```

How long is forever:

- `ps aux`: waited 30 minutes, doesn't come with a full list
- `fio` to finish: waited 30 minutes, doesn't finish at all
- `cat test.img`: Finishish in couple of seconds, it is a 1gb file with /dev/null
- `rm test.img`: waited 30 minutes, doesn't come with any output
  Does someone has ANY suggestions?
- `vi test.txt` added word Test and wq, saves file, but `rm test.txt` hangs (for at least 30 minutes)

Comment: "RAID becomes read-only" is a certain state which is possible but not evident from your findings. When it fails, show `dmesg` without any `grep`; errors might be not with the RAID, but with something else, for instance, the file system (e.g. a silent corruption, which doesn't prevent mounting but manifests itself when changing into some directory or reading some file). Also, "forever" is for how long? Some timeout messages may appear in `dmesg` after 2 minutes. Also, what does show `cat /proc/mdstat` and `mount` when it fails?

Comment: I looked at `dmesg`, and there are really no errors related to this (besides kubernetes failing all over the place), so only the normal boot messages are shown, and when it happens no errors of any kind are being displayed.

Comment: `mount` is full of mounts from kubernetes, and the rw mount point to `/mnt/mounting_point`, and my RAM disk.

Forever is this long: I run the command, and after 10 minutes it did not finish, then I normally give up..

Also just did MemTest86, which completes without errors...

Comment: Added details in post.

Comment: Well, strange. RAID certainly does not become read-only, else it'll be written in the mdstat. Can you force a filesystem check (for all filesystems)? The easiest way to force it for ext4 that couldn't be unmounted (e.g. root) is to `tune2fs -C 31 -c 30 /dev/xxx` it and then reboot; it will set check for every 30 mounts and set current mount count to 31 to trigger a check next boot.

Comment: I always do a `fsck` on boot on /dev/md0, might be overkill, but better safe than sorry. Since it is not mounted as root, so I can always perform the fsck before mounting.